# How to enable Json pretty print on Apigility ApiProblem response?

Tags: json, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, hal-json

I would like to know how to set ApiProblem response to pretty print Json by default.

Comment: How do you mean pretty print json? Json is a data format without styling.

Comment: Something like json_decode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) by default on every Api response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes on class `ApiProblemResponse`. I set the property `$jsonFlags` to ***128***, which is related to `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` code.

Here's the full class code with my changes:

```
<?php

namespace Zend\ApiProblem;

use Zend\Http\Response;

/**
 * Represents an ApiProblem response payload
 */
class ApiProblemResponse extends Response
{
    /**
     * @var ApiProblem
     */
    protected $apiProblem;

    /**
     * Flags to use with json_encode JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $jsonFlags = 128;

    /**
     * @param ApiProblem $apiProblem
     */
    public function __construct(ApiProblem $apiProblem)
    {
        $this->apiProblem = $apiProblem;
        $this->setCustomStatusCode($apiProblem->status);
        $this->setReasonPhrase($apiProblem->title);

        // Just comment/remove these lines to prevent flags from being overwrited
        //if (defined('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) {
          //$this->jsonFlags = constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES');
        //}
    }

    /**
     * @return ApiProblem
     */
    public function getApiProblem()
    {
        return $this->apiProblem;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the content
     *
     * Serializes the composed ApiProblem instance to JSON.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {

        return json_encode($this->apiProblem->toArray(), $this->jsonFlags);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve headers
     *
     * Proxies to parent class, but then checks if we have an content-type
     * header; if not, sets it, with a value of "application/problem+json".
     *
     * @return \Zend\Http\Headers
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        $headers = parent::getHeaders();
        if (!$headers->has('content-type')) {
            $headers->addHeaderLine('content-type', 'application/problem+json');
        }
        return $headers;
    }

    /**
     * Override reason phrase handling
     *
     * If no corresponding reason phrase is available for the current status
     * code, return "Unknown Error".
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReasonPhrase()
    {
        if (! empty($this->reasonPhrase)) {
            return $this->reasonPhrase;
        }

        if (isset($this->recommendedReasonPhrases[$this->statusCode])) {
            return $this->recommendedReasonPhrases[$this->statusCode];
        }

        return 'Unknown Error';
    }
}
```

Inside my controller i used:

```
return new ApiProblemResponse(
  new ApiProblem(ApiProblemResponse::STATUS_CODE_501, 'Example of JSON_PRETTY_PRINT response.')
);
```

And did the trick:

```
{
    "type": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/Protocols\/rfc2616\/rfc2616-sec10.html",
    "title": "Not Implemented",
    "status": 501,
    "detail": "Example of JSON_PRETTY_PRINT response."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `HalJsonStrategy` used for rendering in ZF-Hal. This strategy [extends the default ZF2 `JsonStrategy`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/View/HalJsonStrategy.php#L21). This strategy renders view models of type [`HalJsonModel` which extends](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/View/HalJsonModel.php#L17) the default ZF2 `JsonModel` class.
Rendering happens with [the `HalJsonRenderer` which extends](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/View/HalJsonRenderer.php#L23) the default ZF2 `JsonRenderer` class.

You can customize all this by changing the rendering strategy to some custom strategy or otherwise by setting another renderer (a custom one extending the existing one) inside the `HalJsonStrategy`.

Not sure what is the best way. 
Since all this hal-json rendering logic is built on top of the default ZF2 json rendering logic it might very well be possible to change the way the current renderer outputs your json by just changing the configuration as you would normally do in ZF2 to achieve pretty printed output.

Maybe this page [here](https://juriansluiman.nl/article/140/pretty-print-json-in-your-rest-api) will help you to achieve what you want.

### Summary:

What it comes down to is to exchange the `Json::encode` call in [the `render` method in the `JsonRenderer` class](https://github.com/seventy6ix/ZF2/blob/master/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/JsonRenderer.php#L127) (or a render call) to `Json::prettyPrint`

---

**Note:**
It might be that the reason to do this is for reviewing your json code in a readable way in your browser window. There are many json plugins that can help you with this and it will be a much easier solution.

Comment: I'll try this solution. Thank you!